# Social sites slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make a social media slider with jQuery, HTML and CSS. [This is available as a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kraftingerlp/pxposhau/).

Can I improve or debug any elements of it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sa').hover(
  function() {
 
    $(this).css("margin-left") == "130px"
    {
        $('#sociallili').stop().animate({"margin-left": '+=130'});
    }
  },
    function(){
    {
        $('#sociallili').stop().animate({"margin-left": '-=130'});
    }
    }

  );
         });
```

```css
div#sociallili {
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
div#sociallili>a.sa {
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-color:green;
    border:solid 1px no-color;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slili" id="sociallili">
    <a class="sa" href="#"><br/></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a job you should use CSS3 transitions for, as well as using the correct `border-radius` to only make your top right and bottom right corners rounded, which means you can use this element *without* having to calculate it. You should also use `transform`, that way your element can have *any* size and it will work as expected:

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
div.socialList {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-80%);
  transform: translateX(-80%);
  /* You can even use calc() to allow a certain amount of pixels to be visible. */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 40px));
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 40px));
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 400ms;
  transition: transform 400ms;
}

div.socialList > a {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  /* `no-color` does not exist. Just use border: none.*/
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
div.socialList:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(0px));
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(calc(0px));
}
```

```html
<div class="socialList">
    <a href="#"><br/></a>
</div>
```

I have use `-webkit-` prefixes because I use Safari, so be sure to use all prefixes. Apart from this, I used `calc()` inside one of the statements, this is the last one I do. This is because the `calc` allows you to set the amount of pixels that poke out more accurately. IE9, however, does not support using `calc` inside the `transform` statement, so the `80%` will work in those.

This is a case where Javascript would do more harm than good and the tools are provided. Only older browsers would have to use JS, and you might as well simple give them *no transition whatsoever*. If you want a fallback you could still use your `margin` fallback for older browser and use `calc()` to reset the margin (`margin: -200px; margin: calc(0px);`).

(Please be aware that transform still uses the original space of the element in the document flow, so using a `margin` with a CSS transition might be the best solution depending on where you are going to use it)

Comment: @KraftingerLp Ha. Always nice to hear. Good luck (:

Comment: I´m trying it now ,but it doesn´t displaying.  Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There could be an awfull lot of reasons for that. Try stripping code until things change again to see whats causing this. Thats how i debug. Good luck.